# Multiselect field in SuiteCRM webtolead form causes warning

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, sugarcrm, suitecrm

I have webtolead form in SuiteCRM and multiselect field in it. When i fill the form and click 'Sumbit' there is a warning `Warning: mysqli_real_escape_string() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given in D:\OpenServer\OpenServer\domains\localhost\SuiteCRM-7.8.2\include\database\MysqliManager.php on line 260`

The problem is in multiselect field. The data from it doesn't fall into created lead in SuiteCRM.

MySQL - 5.5 , PHP - 5.6
How i can i solve this problem?

Maybe there is a way to create my own form and transfer information to SuiteCRM?

Answer (score 0):

Does the form data make it into the CRM system?

PHP Warnings generally don't affect overall deliverability/functionality of the system. I would encourage you to

- disable [display_errors](http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.display-errors) on your PHP configuration (i.e. adjust your `php.ini` to set the `display_errors` option to false).
- file a bug report with the SuiteCRM team on the [GitHub Issue Tracker](https://github.com/salesagility/SuiteCRM/issues). Warnings like this are usually easy to resolve in the code base.